# Screenreader Accessibility: two buttons, one label

Tags: forms, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Legend</legend>
            <span>Labeltext</span>
            <button aria-pressed="false">Filter 1</button>
            <button aria-pressed="true">Filter 2</button>
        </fieldset>
```

The span-Element acts like a label for the two buttons. Each button acts independently. As the design is given, it is not possible to change the structure of the text.

As far as i know, it is not possible to add one label to two buttons.

Is it sufficient to extend the label of the buttons and add the "label" (span) into it? Like this: `<button aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Labeltext Filter 1">Filter 1</button>`

The alternative would be to use the Checkbox Pattern from the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG), which would change the "label" (span) into a heading. But there is no other heading around, so this might be more confusing for screenreader user.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can use the same element as a label for several elements simply by referring to it via `aria-labelledby`.

This would result in the *same* accessible name for both buttons, which is not very helpful. So you will need add their own contents as well. Directly providing it inside `aria-label` would be easiest:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>
  <span>Labeltext</span>
  <button aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Labeltext Filter 1">Filter 1</button>
  <button aria-pressed="true" aria-label="Labeltext Filter 2">Filter 2</button>
</fieldset>
```

I’m curious about the actual use case, since there already is the Legend which sufficiently provides a wrapping label for both buttons. The additional *Labeltext* seems unnecessary.

You can use `aria-describedby` if the *Labeltext* “describes or annotates the current element”:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>
  <span id="button-desc">Labeltext</span>
  <button aria-pressed="false" aria-describedby="button-desc">Filter 1</button>
  <button aria-pressed="true" aria-describedby="button-desc">Filter 2</button>
</fieldset>
```